# Resources to get started on fractional graph coloring algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms, graph-colouring, heuristics

I'm interested in using  fractional graph coloring algorithms/solvers to solve a problem, where is a good place to start? I'm looking to find basic/introductory to state-of-the-art algorithms more than theoretical results at this point.

Scheinerman's book looks great, but the focus seems to be more on theory than algorithms.